# SQL query with JOIN and multiple conditions

Tags: sql, select, join

I'm having trouble formulating a SQL query. I run the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN plans
ON plans.task_id = tasks.id
```

and get this result set:

```
task.id task.description  plan.id plan.task_id plan.date
-------|-----------------|-------|------------|------------
   1    Foo                  1         1        1998-01-01
   2    Foobar               2         2        2012-02-25
   2    Foobar               3         2        2012-12-12
   3    Foobass              4         3        2012-12-24
   4    Bassbar
                       ... and lots of more records
```

Today is 2012-08-03. I want all tasks with the following condition: the task have never been planed *or* the task have been planed in the past but have no future plans.

In the example above the following tasks meet this condition:

- 1 Foo
- 4 Bassbar

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is task 2 called deemed past and future?  What about a task that is in the current week?

Comment: What is plan.week what does that express?

Comment: It represents a week number for a specific year. But you can look at it as an integer. So I want records where plan.week IS NULL or less then current week (eg. 201231).

Comment: How is 20124 a week number?  Are you adding a week number directly to a year?  Why dont you seperate the year and week # ?

Comment: Week 4 the year 2012. :) But thats not relevant it's a simplified example of the real data.

Comment: What do you mean its not relevant?  Why do you have a column that appends a week number to a year?

Comment: I am separating week and year in production, I just wanted to simplify the example.

Comment: Man, it's just sample data! :D

Comment: SELECT DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) gets the week number...

Comment: You'll have to handle the year too, I know its sample data but how can we help you if you do not define the actual columns of your table?  If the schema is faked how can I possibly assist you in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN plans
ON plans.task_id = tasks.id
WHERE plan.week IS NULL OR (plan.week < DATEPART(week, GetDate()) AND plan.Year = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

You should not use `SELECT *`, explicitly write out each column you need.  You didn't mention if you had a year column as well, you'll have to handle the week number and the year.  If you just handle the week # you'll get results across multiple years.

It sounds like you can just use task description???  Why are you basing it on the week column if you can use the task description?

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN plans
ON plans.task_id = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.description = 'Past' OR tasks.description = 'Not planned'
```

Aha I understand your data now, you could have multiple tasks but on different week numbers.  This is simple, just use a query to find the MAX(Week#) GROUP BY the task and then perform the query, Ill write it up give me a minute...

```
  CREATE TABLE #MyTest
(
 TaskID int,
 TaskYear int,
 TaskWeek int
)

INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskYear,TaskWeek)
VALUES (1, 2012, 4)
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskYear,TaskWeek)
VALUES (2, 2012, 5)
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskYear,TaskWeek)
VALUES (2, 2012, 36)
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskYear,TaskWeek)
VALUES (3, 2012, 36)
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskYear,TaskWeek)
VALUES (4, 2012, NULL)
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskYear,TaskWeek)
VALUES (6, 2011, 5)
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskYear,TaskWeek)
VALUES (6, 2010, 36)

SELECT
    TaskID,
    MAX(TaskWeek) AS WeekNumber,
    TaskYear
FROM
  #MyTest
GROUP BY 
    TaskID,
    TaskWeek,
    TaskYear
HAVING MAX(TaskWeek) < DatePart(week, GetDate()) OR MIN(TaskWeek) IS NULL

DROP TABLE #MyTest
```

This will now give you unique rows for each `task.id` with the max week number.

## Final Result

Based on your final comments:

Copy and paste this into sql management studio, I have commented it for you:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTest
(
 TaskID int,
 TaskDate datetime
)

--test for only in the past NOTHING in the future
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID, TaskDate)
VALUES (1, '1998-01-01')

--test for planned in the future NOTHING in the past
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskDate)
VALUES (3, '2012-12-24')

--test for no plan as all (IS NULL)
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskDate)
VALUES (4, null)

--test for planned in the past but has an upcoming event in the future
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskDate)
VALUES (6, '2011-12-23')
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskDate)
VALUES (6, '2012-12-23')
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskDate)

--test for planned in the past, NO upcoming event in the future
VALUES (8, '2012-1-23')
INSERT INTO #MyTest(TaskID,TaskDate)
VALUES (8, '2012-6-23')

--result should show:
-- task id = 1 (because of: performed in past but nothing in the future)
-- task id = 4 (because of: no plan at all) 
-- task id = 8 (because of: only past)

SELECT
    TaskID,
    YEAR(TaskDate) AS TheYear,
    DatePart(week, TaskDate) AS WeekNumber
FROM
  #MyTest
WHERE 
--handle no planning of a task...
((TaskDate IS NULL)
--eliminate any task id that is out in the future
OR TaskID NOT IN (SELECT TaskID FROM #MyTest WHERE TaskDate > GetDate()))
GROUP BY
    TaskID,
    Year(TaskDate),
    DatePart(week, TaskDate)

DROP TABLE #MyTest
```

Comment: Right what does that mean?  What is plan.week ?

Comment: This will not yield the result I'm after. It will return task 1, 2 and 4. I just want 1 and 4.

Comment: You need to word your question a lot better, I still don't understand what you are after.  The reason it returns 1,2 and 4 is because of my condition, take my condition and modify it to fit your needs.  Look at row 2 and 4 what makes them different? To me with that sample data mine works fine locally here.

Comment: I've tried to update the question. Is it clear now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't the plan.year be included somehow?

Comment: I included it in the where condition are you just looking to run this query for the `year` meaning you only care about a year at a time?

Comment: No I care about all previous plans.

Comment: Ok so you care about all years...give me another minute

Comment: Still need more information, my query will work based on your sample data.  What you have not mentioned is what if the same task was performed in 2010, and 2011 which record do you want?  To understand what I mean see my sample data in the `INSERT` statements, notice task id 6...completed in 2010 and 2011.

Comment: I have changed the question once more, I hope it's more clear now. I removed the week and year and replaced with a date. Please read it again and thanks for all the help.

Comment: Again I ask you based on your sample data, what if task 1 appears multiple times completed for different dates.  1998, 2010, 2011 do you want the latest one?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by completed for different days? A task can be planned to a date. It can be planned multiple times to different dates. With other words: theres a one to many relationship between task and plans.

Comment: I dont care how many plans a task have. I just care about task that has no plans at all or just have plans in the past (plans with a date before today).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really sorry that my question was unclear at first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14892/discussion-between-sven-and-jonh)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
LEFT JOIN plans
ON plans.task_id = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.description = 'Past' OR tasks.description = 'Not planned'
```

Comment: what is plan.week I see its a number but what does it represent?

Comment: i'm guessing its the year "2012" followed by the week number. But i see no point in filtering on that if that data is already reflected in task.description.

Comment: That is a very bad way to store a week number.

Comment: I will second that assessment.

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not normalize my example data guys, won't happen again! :)